# Viewing a custom list vertically

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-list

I'm using SP2010, and need a specific view of my custom list.
My custom list is defined as the follows:

```
Column 1 name = "Project Name"               Data type = Single line of text
Column 2 name = "Step one complete"          Data type = Choice (Yes or No)
Column 3 name = "Step two complete"          Data type = Choice (Yes or No)
Column 4 name = "Pass through the gate"      Data type = Choice (Yes or No)
```

I am trying to create a custom view of my list to be like the image below:

[image: screenshot]

Is this possible to do through a custom view of the list, or is there a better out of the box way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same requirement in one of my project. For this i added a content query webpart and i added the xslt in the ItemStyles.xsl, with custom styles. That pulls the all the coloums in the list.

I think it is the one of the solution to you.

Edit:

```
<xsl:template name="PageBlocksWithoutDescription" match="Row[@Style='PageBlocksWithoutDescription']" mode="itemstyle">            
    <xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'PublishingPageImage'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="LinkTarget">
        <xsl:if test="@OpenInNewWindow = 'True'" >_blank</xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div>       
    <ul style=" width:1000px;">
    <a href="{@BlockUrl}">
    <li style="background-color: #F99E2E;color: #FFF;display: inline-table;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 13px;height: 130px;list-style: none outside none;padding: 10px 15px 5px 17px;width: 269px;margin:0px 3px 12px 8px;display:inline-block;float:left;">
    <div style=" font-family:Segoe UI Semibold; font-size: 16px;text-transform:uppercase">
    <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
    </div>     
    </li>
    </a>
    </ul>               
    </div>        
</xsl:template>
```

Add it at the end of ItemStyles.xsl and in the content query webpart-> edit webpart->Content Query Tool Part->Presentation->Styles->Item Styles you will get "PageBlocksWithoutDescription". Select it and Below that Feeds To Dispaly tab select the fields to display.

Comment: can you provide us the XSLT?

Comment: I've merged your other answer into this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking into a DataView, XsltListView, or ContentQuery web part for this. Theyre all out of the box web parts that allow you to customize the presentation with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with custom views out of the box. You will need to write a custom web part for this.

Comment: Really? I only want to order it vertically so to speak I can sort out the formatting with some JQuery\CSS.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to create your own code to get a Pivot chart display like you're looking for.  nothing like that exists out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not opening for me... There is a way in out of the box to view the list vertically... click modify view>>under the section style select the view style 'Boxed'... Hope this helps... you can even edit in SharePoint designer to fulfill your requirement...